# React Native or Intel XDK for better performance native app

Tags: android, ios, iphone, react-native, intel-xdk

I've to do a quick development for a prototype app and I've decided to go for a cross-platform HTML5 tool/platform.

I've shortlisted Intel XDK for its developer-friendly IDE, React native for its performance as a native build compared to others and Ionic for the nice UI with Angular and available themes.

I need native like performance and nice UI with some responsive themes, which would be better recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently? Cordova + Intel XDK has more support and a larger feature set. There are even examples that come with the XDK of video games that perform at near native speeds. Cordova uses JS APIs to hook into native functionality, but at the end of the day, you're still running web code.

React Native is different in that you're building an application using native components, but expressed using React's JSX. Arguably, because you're building the app using native components, you *should* see better performance (and get a more native look/feel).

**Cordova:**

- Uses a web view
- Taps into native functionality with jsAPIs
- Has been around longer, and has more support
- *Code once, run everywhere*

**React Native:**

- Android support appears to be a little shaky? (could be wrong here)
- Builds display using native components
- Newer, but backed by a powerhouse (and gaining traction)
- *Learn once, code everywhere*

Honestly, using either technology you should be fine. Both have shown that they're up for most challenges.

I would probably push you to Cordova + Intel XDK for increased support, easier for webdevs to pick up, and it's more mature. React may very well eclipse it, but I don't think it's quite there yet.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Awesome thank you for your inputs. I can manage most of my screens with web view. But I do have some calls to the hardware and real time calculations, for which Intel+ Cordova seems to be fine. I'll start with Intel as it seems pretty simple and straight. Thanks a ton for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

with cordova The biggest advantage you get, is the single code base to develop without learning any new technology, if you are already a web developer But the application runs in the webview, and not natively on the hardware, which makes it less performant than the native iOS applications or native Android.

in React You need to understand the Framework(react), you need to understand JSX (in iOS simulator, You also need to work with Xcode)

With React native, you get ease of development, better performance and great user experience in the end